# Remove Nth line from both files if line in one file matches

Tags: text-processing

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`. They both have X lines. Some lines in `file2` are empty(they match `^$`). If line I is empty in `file2`, I want to remove line I from both files. Example:

`File1`:

```
ad
dada

da
dad


a
```

`File2`:

```
dada


da
dada
dada
da
(empty line)
```

Resulting `file1`:

```
ad
da
dad


(empty line)
```

Resulting `file2`:

```
Dada
da
dada
dada
da
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fFile.html#Getline_002fFile) in this case:

```
$ awk '{ getline ln < "File1"; if(!/^$/){print ln > "tmp1"; print > "tmp2"} }' File2
$ cat tmp1
ad
da
dad


$ cat tmp2
dada
da
dada
dada
da
```

Then `mv` the output files for inplace editing if needed

Comment: This is simple(one-liner), readable and flexible approach. I like it, and used it. Thanks!